# SQL: Getting the user's info and their latest dated record from another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

Patient: p_id, name, age
&
MedicalRecord: id, p_id, date

and I need to select all from Patient together with the date of their latest MedicalRecord.
The desired result would be

| p.id | name | age | date(latest) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 20 | 2020/12/20 |
| 2 | Hero | 18 | 2020/12/18 |

I'm currently stuck at

```
SELECT *
  FROM Patient
  JOIN (SELECT
            MedicalRecord.p_id,
            MedicalRecord.date
        FROM MedicalRecord) x ON Patient.p_id = x.p_id
```

This will give me the result below, but I only need to show each Patient ONCE with their MedicalHistory's latest date.

| p.id | name | age | p_id | date(latest) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 20 | 1 | 2020/12/20 |
| 1 | John | 20 | 1 | 2020/12/15 |
| 2 | Hero | 18 | 2 | 2020/12/18 |

THANK YOU.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old school way to do this would be to use joins:

```sql
SELECT p.*, mr.*
FROM Patient p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT mr1.*
    FROM MedicalRecord mr1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT p_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
        FROM MedicalRecord
        GROUP BY p_id
    ) mr2
        ON mr2.p_id = mr1.p_id AND
           mr2.max_date = mr1.date
) mr
    ON mr.p_id = p.id
```

With analytic functions, we can use `ROW_NUMBER` here for some slightly more terse code:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.*, mr.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY mr.date DESC) rn
    FROM Patient p
    LEFT JOIN MedicalRecord mr ON mr.p_id = p.id
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Using the old school way how can I show the Patient even if they have no record? sorry I forgot to mention it in my question.

Comment: @Sciryl Replace the `INNER JOIN`s with `LEFT JOIN`s and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard sql analytical function `row_number` as follows:

```
Select * from
(SELECT P.*, row_number() over (partition by p.id order by mr.date desc) as rn
  FROM Patient P
  JOIN MedicalRecord mr ON mr.p_id = p.id) t
Where rn = 1
```

You can also use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT P.*
  FROM Patient P
  JOIN MedicalRecord mr ON mr.p_id = p.id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (select 1 from MedicalRecord mr1
         Where mr1.p_id = mr.p_id
           And mr1.date > mr.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Patient
  JOIN (SELECT
            MedicalRecord.p_id,
            max(MedicalRecord.date) [date(latest)]
        FROM MedicalRecord
        group by MedicalRecord.p_id
        ) x ON Patient.p_id = x.p_id
```